# Inheritance in java collection interfaces

Tags: java, collections, interface

There are some inheritance relationship in Java collection interfaces. For example, `Collection<T>` interface will extend `Iterable<T>`.
I checked the source code in JDK, some methods defined in base class get repeated in sub classes several times. For example: 
   `Interable<T>` interface defined a method  `Iterator<E> iterator();` But in interface `Collection<E>` and `List<T>`,  also contain the same method. In my understanding, since inheritance is used to reduce duplication, why should we define the same method in subclasses?

Answer (score 5):

See in [java.util.List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

"The List interface places additional stipulations, beyond those specified in the Collection interface, on the contracts of the iterator, add, remove, equals, and hashCode methods. Declarations for other inherited methods are also included here for convenience."

Comment: +1 In fact I'd guess the reasons for redeclaring those methods are (as the citation you posted states): 1. being able to add different JavaDoc comments (i.e. the contracts that are mentioned) and 2. as a convenience to provide a quick overview of the available methods.

Answer (score 1):

`Collection` came out in release 1.2, but `Iterable` came out afterwards in release 1.5 to allow for concise for-loops, so I think it was a case of keeping the `Collection` interface and the Javadocs the same between releases.  But you are correct, there is no reason you couldn't remove the `iterator()` method from `Collection`, everything would still compile.

Answer (score 1):

The `Collection` interface *extends* `Iterable`. An abstract superclass implements the methods common to several classes, in the case of lists, it's [`AbstractList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html), with each concrete class (say, `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`) providing the specific implementation details.

In fact, as you've guessed, inheritance is used for reducing code duplication. But precisely because of that, all the subclasses will contain the same operations defined in the superclasses, the implementation details common to several classes will appear only once in the class hierarchy at the abstract class level, and they are not "defined" again in the subclasses - only the parts that change are redefined in concrete subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

The `Iterable` interface was introduced later `since 1.5`. So, earlier to this version only `java.util.Collection` subclasses used to implement `iterator()`.

Later `iterator()` was made standard by introducing `Iterable` interface such that any Class which can iterated can implement this interface.

After introducing `Iterable` interface, the `Collection` interface was also made to extend `Iterable` interface such that `Collection` interface  also implements the standard one.

**For Ex,**

- `java.sql.SQLException` also implements Iterable

Comment: Since he's refering to interfaces there's no overriding involved.